# Android equivalent for HTML5 Canvas CompositeOperation

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

In [HTML5/JavaScript](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2009/02/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html) there is this property

`compositeoperation` for the `canvas` that sets the mode for putting graphics on the canvas (add/xor/over etc...).

What is the equivalent of this behaviour for [Androids `Canvas` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)?

Or do I need to approach it in a different way to achieve the same results as this property?

(*My Java-knowledge is like null++*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I found it after an evening of reading, So I answer my own question:

**[PorterDuffXfermode](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.html)** is the equivalent. (A bit deeper and decoupled than in Javascript.Canvas)

Answer (score 1):

do you want to work with the java canvas class or with the HTML5 Canvas class?

for me, it sound like you should build an android webapp ( http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html ). Within a webapp, you are free to use all HTML5 features as you already know them.

You can even use phonegap in order to access the android hardware easier than with a normal android webapp.

btw: there is a good book about android development with HTML5 : http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/

Comment: that sounds like a great alternative! However, I read the HTML5 support for many android devices was not that good, what is your experience with this?

Comment: my experience is quite good. The webview is a webkit based browser. modernizr reports that this browser supports nearly every feature. But beware - on mobile devices, webkit != webkit. They differ slightly. For instance, android has no scrollbars for textareas.

Comment: There are places where it makes sense to go with webviews, but they are WAY slower than native operations, or than running the same thing in a browser on a computer.  And html canvas stuff can be pretty slow on a computer, if you are doing things at the pixel level.